# Sonar Xerces conflict Findbugs and ivy:report

Tags: ivy, sonarqube, findbugs, xerces

I am trying to get sonar to work for a project with a quality profile that includes Findbugs rules.

However when analyzing the project the sonar anttask chrashes with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.filter.Filter.<init>(Filter.java:134)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs.configureFilter(FindBugs.java:516)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.addFilter(FindBugs2.java:374)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:136)
    ... 50 more
```

on this project the dependencies are resolved with ivy, and has no dependencies on libraries like xerces and xalan. Also i understood that xerces is included included in the JVM and is always a pleasure to deal with...

i've tried to add all sorts of dependencies to use for the sonar.libraries property but with no effect adding the local JRE libs also doesnt seem to have much effect.

How do i get this findbugs analysis to run (in a machine independent way)?

(Sonar version: 4.4, findbugs3 plugin)

Update:
I just found out the source of the conflict is having a  target earlier in the build, removing it fixes it. Ofcourse i very much like to keep my ivy report as well, so the question is still how do i get this to work...?

Comment: Looks like you're facing this bug : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-56 that we haven't manage to reproduce locally. Would you be able to provide a sample Ant project to help us reproducing this issue ?

Comment: i will try to make a clean test case today or tomorrow and update the bug report

Answer (score 12):

After upgrading our sonar to v4.4 and changing Sonar's Quality profile from 'Sonar way' (Java) to 'Sonar way with Findbugs' I came accross this same exception complaining about the SAX2 driving:

```
Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Can not execute Find bugs: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
```

I got around it by adding the driver to my maven command:

> Dorg.xml.sax.driver=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser

Bellow was my actual maven command to clean, compile, run test, analyse code and upload stats to sonar (having the fix in the command line also meets you non machine specific preference fix and requires no change to your source code)

```
$ mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.fai
lure.ignore=true -Dorg.xml.sax.driver=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.
SAXParser sonar:sonar
```

Answer (score 2):

Our Solution for

> Can not execute Findbugs: SAX2 driver class
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser

is not to use

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar
```

in one command, but to invoke sonar in a seperate step

```
mvn clean install
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the issue:
Download xerces-2.9.0.jar from:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxercesjar.htm

Add this jar to (sonar root folder)\extensions\plugins

Try this command in the desired folder

> mvn clean install sonar:sonar

Good luck