# Cannot execute Findbugs in sonar analysis in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, findbugs

I am trying to execute the sonar analysis from jenkins

```
clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarhost:8090 -Dsonar.projectName=demoProject -Dsonar.branch=master


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project demoProject: Can not execute Findbugs: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project demoProject: Can not execute Findbugs
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas to fix it

Comment: `class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser` not found. Make sure you have SAX in the class path

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872710/sonar-xerces-conflict-findbugs-and-ivyreport?

Comment: try to invoke sonar in a seperate command